# How to get JButton properties when looping inside a JPanel.getComponents()

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, components, jbutton

I have a JPanel in which I filled up with JButtons.

```
void addMealsMenuBarTitles() {

    JToggleButton test;
    int i=0;

    for (Categoria c: categories.categorias) {
        test = new JToggleButton(c.categoria);
        test.setForeground(Color.white);
        test.setBackground(new Color(52, 152, 219));
        test.setSize(new Dimension(menuMealsBar.getWidth()/categories.categorias.size(), menuMealsBar.getHeight()));
        test.setLocation(i++*(test.getWidth()), 0);
        menuMealsBar.add(test);
    }

}
```

What I want to do is to access the properties (Border) of the JButtons when looping through the components of that JPanel

```
void addClickEventCategories() {
    for (Component jtb: menuMealsBar.getComponents())

        jtb.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            //jtb.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 0, 5, 0, Color.white));
        }

        @Override public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {}

        @Override public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}

        @Override public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}

        @Override public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
    });
}
```

The error that I'm getting is that the Component does not have the BorderProperty (obviously)... How can i get this work around?

Comment: I tried to do this: for (Component jtb: (JToggleButton[])menuMealsBar.getComponents()) but it didn't work. It crushes at runtime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably use something more like...

```
for (Component comp: menuMealsBar.getComponents()) {
    if (comp instanceof JToggleButton) {
         JToggleButton jtb = (JToggleButton)comp;
```

As you shouldn't make assumptions about what a container actually contains (you'd be surprised a lot of the time ;))

Another solution might be to do something similar within the `mouseClicked` method

```
@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    Component comp = e.getComponent();
    if (comp instanceof JToggleButton) {
        JToggleButton jtb = (JToggleButton)comp;
        jtb.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 0, 5, 0, Color.white));
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. If I do so, jtb won't change comp as I am only instantiating a new object. 2. I cannot instantiate a variable inside and if

Comment: There's no new objects been created, you are simply casting from a `Component` to a `JToggleButton` based on you investigation of the type of object which you have...

Comment: Jezz!! It worked! Thanks! (How can I mark you as the answer? I'm kind of n00b to this forum)... Maybe you can help me solve out this last "riddle". I want that when I click on the button, it changes its border to, say white, but i want the rest to disable their borders as well. Kind of like a radio button

Comment: That's a little more difficult, as you would need to know all the buttons in the group. You could use `ButtonGroup` and monitor the `selected` states of the buttons and make your changes based on which buttons are selected

Comment: k! i couldn't work with abstract buttons so... I found this loopy way to do it, not the best! but it sure works:

Comment: `<code>jtb.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    jtb.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 0, 5, 0, Color.white));
                    
                    for (Component comp2: menuMealsBar.getComponents()) {
                        JButton jtb2 = (JButton)comp2;
                        if (comp2 != e.getComponent()) {
                            jtb2 = (JButton)comp2;
                            jtb2.setBorder(null);
                        }
                    }
         }</code>`

Answer (score 1):

```
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        //jtb.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 0, 5, 0, Color.white));
    }
```

You can get the component from the MouseEvent:

```
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        JToggleButton button = (JToggleButton)e.getSource();
        button.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 0, 5, 0, Color.white));
    }
```

Comment: I like it @camickr ... Where should i put this override on? The JPanel?